# Multiple lambdas strung together with SQS not passing to destinations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a series of lambda functions strung together with a series of SQS queues. Basically it looks something like this:

```
Lambda(foo) => Queue(Alpha) => Lambda(bar) => Queue(Beta) => Lambda(baz)
```

In this case Queue(Alpha) is a [Destination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) of Lambda(foo) and event-source for Lambda(bar).

We expect Lambda(foo) to successfully execute, then pass a message to Queue(Alpha) which fires Lambda(bar). Then, given Lambda(bar) succeeds, it will pass a message to Queue(Beta), which fires Lambda(baz).

In reality, invoking Lambda(foo) will send a message to Queue(Alpha), which fires Lambda(bar); but then processing halts. We've checked logs and everything is successful, but no message is sent to Queue(beta). To rule out permissions issues, we've invoked Lambda(bar) directly which does send a message to Queue(beta) and invokes Lambda(baz) as we'd hope.

All Destination connections are setup as async. The test invocation we've been running is done like so (naming for example so can ignore details there):

```
aws2 lambda invoke --function-name Queue(foo) --invocation-type Event --payload '{ \"input\": \"jphenow\" }' response.json
```

Does anyone have ideas what we could be missing here? At the moment of setup, these are all async nodejs functions that execute `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` but they will be a mix of various different languages soon.

Explicitly calling SQS is also not out of the question, though not preferable for at least a portion of our architecture.

Any help or clues would be greatly appreciated!

--

Of note, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669947/aws-lambda-w-sqs-trigger-sqs-lambda-destinations-never-adds-to-destination-qu) post, but they're having issues with the first destination working, not the subsequent queues. My gut says it's a similar flavor of issue, but I can't tell how I'd further control that.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to know, but the example payload you have isn't what you will get from SQS. Keep in mind that the SQS payload will be a batch of SQS messages.

Comment: Right that was an issue at first, but they're now built to parse out the actual given message - worth noting that in each case that they've been invoked via SQS they've worked. Also of note, the first queue they go through works, just not the second - and on.

Comment: I would add logging before and after the call to SQS. What language is the lambda written in?

Comment: It's all node right now, but only to get the initial workflow proved out. They are logging and everything is successful in both stages. Another note to call out from above is that mimicking the SQS shape I can make `bar => Beta => baz` work and separately `foo => Alpha => bar` works; leading me to believe it's not as much code related as it is configuration.

Comment: I just reread your comment as well. It's not _calling_ to SQS - it's using Lambda Destinations - Edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Oh! Have you made sure you have the permissions setup correctly then? I am not exactly sure what those permissions need to be, but this sounds like a permissions issue. You can probably see the error in CloudTrail.

Comment: Good question - I would think portions of `foo => Alpha => bar` and `bar => Beta => baz` wouldn't work if that were the case. I suppose I could try to insert a message rather than invoking these to see how that works. Right now foo has access to send to Alpha, Alpha has access to invoke bar, bar has send access to Beta, and so on.  Perhaps that's not correct?

Comment: Perhaps this: "Your execution policy of the lambda must have permission to put, publish, or invoke your destination source. The same way as if you were doing things in your business logic code." [Found here](https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-destinations-what-we-learned-the-hard-way/)

Comment: Hmm yea that's sort of ruled out by `foo => Alpha => bar` working as well as `bar => Beta => baz` (when invoking `foo` and then separately invoking `bar`) - is it not? It would also be kind of silly if it required `foo` to have direct permission to `bar` and so on - which isn't to say it's not a possible reason.

Comment: I just had a thought. The destinations work when a lambda is invoked asynchronously. I don’t think a lambda triggered from an SQS queue is asynchronous, because a failed execution puts the message back in the queue. I suppose that could be done with a destinations type model under the hood. Either way, just a thought. Destinations are pretty new and the doc is not great.

Comment: This is the conclusion I've been reaching as well, but hoping someone else had a "no no you're definitely doing this wrong" key for me :-) Thanks for playing along. I'll leave this open for now, but I've started migrating to using SQS from within the function directly which is already working anyways. I was just hoping to let AWS do some things for me :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours and @JasonWadsworth's conclusion is absolutely correct. It's quite straightforward actually.

- Lambda functions "triggered" by an SQS message event are invoked **synchronously**, as per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html):

> Lambda polls the queue and invokes your function synchronously with an
>   event that contains queue messages.

- Destinations only works when the lambda function is invoked **asynchronously**, as alluded to in [your link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-destinations-for-asynchronous-invocations/):

> ... AWS Lambda Destinations for asynchronous invocations.

(Although at no point does it explicitly state that synchronous invocations are not supported, a quick google will verify that from other sources.)

- You invoked your function from the CLI **asynchronously**.

> `--invocation-type Event`

As per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html):

> To invoke a function asynchronously, set InvocationType to Event.

Therefore what happened was:

1. `Lambda(foo)` was invoked asynchronously. Because the invocation was asynchronous,
2. The function result was written to `Queue(Alpha)`. Because you've set `Lambda(bar)` as a lambda trigger on this queue, and because Lambda invokes functions synchronously based on SQS messages,
3. `Lambda(bar)` was invoked synchronously. Because it was invoked synchronously,
4. `Queue(Beta)` was not written to, and the pipeline stopped there.

We have a very similar pipeline with lambda functions and queues, the only difference is our functions write to the next queue in the pipeline using the SQS sdk. Not sure if it's the best way, but it's certainly one way to do it.

Comment: Awesome yea this lines up with my conclusions as a result of comment discussion above. Thanks for outlining more detailed summary here! I wound up getting it to work with SDK - I had been avoiding since it adds a bit of weight to each function, but otherwise works perfectly.