# AWS Lambda SNS Destinations not working on failure or success

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Reference : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669947/aws-lambda-w-sqs-trigger-sqs-lambda-destinations-never-adds-to-destination-qu) said : only async lambda execution only work for destination.

Lambda code :

```
const AWSManager = require('./AWSManager.js');
const request = require('request-promise'); 

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  var input = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
  console.log(event.region);
  //console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
  // TODO implement
  var secret_name, region_name;
  if(event.secretName){
    secret_name= event.secretName;
    region_name = event.region;
    
  }else{
    secret_name= "test/"
    region_name = "us-east-1"
  }
  console.log(secret_name)
  var secret = await AWSManager.getSecret(secret_name)
  //console.log('mysecret: ' + secret )
  var secret_values = JSON.parse(secret);
  //var request = require('request');
  var okta_org_url = secret_values['okta_org_url']
  var okta_token = secret_values['okta_token']
  var api_endpoint = okta_org_url + "api/v1/users?limit=25"
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': api_endpoint,
    'headers': {
       // header information
    }
  };
  var api_response = await request(options).then(res => res).catch(err => err)
 
 
  return {
    "statusCode": 200
  }
};
```

Code execute properly only SNS destination doesn't work. SNS destination has email protocol subscription for sending email whenever fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found answer it was mistake only.

As per explaination given in [AWS Lambda w/ SQS trigger, SQS Lambda Destinations, never adds to destination queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669947/aws-lambda-w-sqs-trigger-sqs-lambda-destinations-never-adds-to-destination-qu) is correct only for calling lambda async you have to run different command. And test input from UI doesn't work like async. It works as sync call.

```
aws lambda invoke \     
--function-name lambdaname \     
--invocation-type Event \     
--payload '{ "name": "Bob" }' \     
response.json
```

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html#examples

Here is list call support lambda asynchronously and synchronously:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/