# Is SQS to Lambda to SNS Possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Can SNS be triggered from this setup:

[image: sqs to lambda to sns]

I have read:

- [AWS Lambda SNS Destinations not working on failure or success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418983/aws-lambda-sns-destinations-not-working-on-failure-or-success)
- [AWS Lambda w/ SQS trigger, SQS Lambda Destinations, never adds to destination queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669947/aws-lambda-w-sqs-trigger-sqs-lambda-destinations-never-adds-to-destination-qu)

but I don't fully understand.

Lambda's SNS destination is not being triggered, but SQS sends to Lambda and Lambda successfully finishes.

**What happens currently?**

SQS sends to Lambda but Lambda does not send to SNS. No response from Lambda is sent to SNS. Is that because I am using SQS as the trigger? I want Lambda to send the response to SNS.

**What have I tried**

I have used boto3 (python) to trigger SNS within the Lambda function, and it works, but I would rather have SNS triggered when Lambda function completes.

**What am I trying to do?**

I send a payload (event) to SQS from my python-based backend. I chose SQS because I want things to be retried if the lambda function fails for some reason. On successful completion, I want to send the Lambda response to an SNS HTTPS endpoint that will send to my backend webhook.

---

Long-winded explanation and recreation steps:

Steps:

- Go to SQS, create queue named "SO-76795744", keep all defaults, click "Create queue".
- Go to Lambda, create function named "SO-76795744", Python 3.10, x86_64, keep rest of defaults, click "Create function"
- The default Lambda function code provided by Lambda would work but you can use this as well to see the event message in Cloudwatch:

```
import json
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    logger.info('Lambda function is executing!')
    logger.info(json.dumps(event))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

- Go to SNS, create topic named "SO-76795744", select "Standard", keep everything the defaults, click "Create topic"
- Edit Lambda's execution role policy with this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/SO-76795744:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:SO-76795744"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:SO-76795744"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Go back to lambda function, add SQS trigger, batch size 1, click Add
- Go to lambda function, add SNS destination, Asynchronous invocation, On success, SNS topic, SO-76795744 topic, click "Save"
- Go to SNS topic, make "Email-JSON" subscription for the purposes of testing this, confirm subscription

### TEST SQS

- Go to SQS `SO-76795744`, click "Send and receive messages" button, enter anything into the message body and click "Send message"
- Go to Lambda function > Monitor tab, click "View Cloudwatch logs", verify the only log

Now notice, you will not receive an SNS message via email. You just won't. My question is WHY?

### TEST SNS

- Go to SNS Topic SO-76795744, click "Publish message", enter subject and message body and send.

You should get an email from SNS proving that SNS is working.

Comment: Yes. However, without seeing your code or how your SNS topic is setup I couldn't tell you why it isn't working

Comment: @Mickers I added the basic recreation steps. Maybe you will see something I forgot to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because SQS->Lambda workflow uses `synchronous` invocation (see official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)), so your SNS destination is not used, because it only applies to async lambdas.

While the SQS->Lambda flow itself is asynchronous from client's perspective, the way SQS to Lambda is implemented on AWS backend is using `sync` lambda invocation: AWS Lambda polls SQS queue periodically and if it finds any message it then invokes your Lambda function using Request/Response invocation type (which is synchronous). AWS Lambda service then waits for Lambda response to decide if it needs to delete message from SQS queue (if it gets 200/success response) or if message needs to remain in the queue to be retried later (if response is not successful). I suspect that the need to get this response is why AWS uses sync invocation.

Comment: Got it. So SQS -> Lambda -> SNS is not possible unless SNS is invoked within the Lambda function code (it sounds like).

Comment: @Jarad - Yes, I think that's right